How to modify large amounts of data using pandas
As shown in this code, I need to use certain data in one table as a basis to modify another table and add some information. When this kind of table information scale is large, this violent traversal method is very inefficient. How should I modify it? Moreover, multiple sheets need to be compared, which makes the efficiency even lower.
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 321, 456, 543], 'name': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'www']})
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 321, 456, 543], 'name': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'www'], 'complete': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'], 'course_name':['AA', 'BB', 'AA', 'DD'], 'complete_date': ['1.1', '1.2', '1.1', '1.5']})
df_1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
group_df = df_1.groupby('course_name')
info = dict()
for course_name, course_df in group_df:
    info[course_name]=[]
    def process(row):
            info[course_name].append(Subscriber(*row.tolist()))

    get_info = course_df.loc[course_df["complete"] == "yes"]
    get_columns = ['name', 'complete_date']
    finish_df = get_info[get_columns]
    Subscriber = namedtuple('Subscriber', ['name', 'complete_date'])
    finish_df.apply(process, axis = 1)
# print(info)
# {'AA': [Subscriber(name='xxx', complete='yes'), Subscriber(name='zzz', complete='yes')], 'BB': [Subscriber(name='yyy', complete='yes')], 'DD': [Subscriber(name='www', complete='yes')]}
'''modify df'''
names = set(df['name'])
for course in info.keys():
      for name, date in info[course]:
            if name in names:
                  df.loc[df['name'] == name, course] = date + 'yes' 
                  pass
# print(df)


Welcome here, with the current output, it looks like a pivot would do the job, something like df_1.reset_index().assign(val=lambda x: x['complete_date']+'yes').pivot(index=['id', 'name'], columns='course_name', values='val') plus a bit of cosmetic. But I assume your real case is a bit more complex, could you elaborate if this solution does not fill your need?

Thank you very much and sorry for the late reply. Yes, the requirements will be a little more complicated than this, because the table is used to maintain personnel information, and subsequent information will be used to add to the original table instead of overwriting it. I'll think about how to accomplish it,

As Ben.T is pointing out in the comments, a pivot approach would do the job. Here is an example of how you can do this:
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 321, 456, 543], 'name': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'www']})
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 321, 456, 543], 'name': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'www'], 'complete': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'], 'course_name': ['AA', 'BB', 'AA', 'DD'], 'complete_date': ['1.1', '1.2', '1.1', '1.5']})

completed_courses = df_1[df_1['complete'] == 'yes']

pivot_df = completed_courses.pivot_table(index='id', columns='course_name', values='complete_date', aggfunc='first')

result_df = df.set_index('id').join(pivot_df, on='id')
result_df = result_df.fillna('')

for col in pivot_df.columns:
    result_df[col] = result_df[col].apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x != '' else x)

result_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(result_df)


which gives you
    id name   AA   BB   DD
0  123  xxx  yes          
1  321  yyy       yes     
2  456  zzz  yes          
3  543  www            yes

